# How to select all columns of a bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the follow bigquery table:

```
+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------------+
|     links.href      | links.rel |     dados.dataHora      | dados.sequencia |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------------+
| https://www.url.com | self      | 2017-03-16 16:27:10 UTC |               2 |
|                     |           | 2017-03-16 16:35:34 UTC |               1 |
|                     |           | 2017-03-16 19:50:32 UTC |               3 |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------------+
```

and I want select all rows. So, I try the follow query:

```
SELECT * FROM [my_project:a_import.my_table] LIMIT 100
```

But, I have a bad *(and sad)* error:

```
Error: Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time. Found links_rel and dados_dataHora
```

Please, can anybody help me?

Comment: try in BigQuery Standard SQL - `SELECT * FROM \`my_project.a_import.my_table\` LIMIT 100`

Comment: Also if you are bound to Legacy SQL - check FLATTEN syntax at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#from

Comment: Or uncheck the "flatten results" option with legacy SQL, but that requires setting an output table. Using standard SQL is the better option.